# Pyspark iterative column addition memory leak

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have been attempting to perform some iterative computation on pyspark dataframes. Columns are added to the df based on previous columns.  However I am noting that the memory used keeps increasing.  A simple example is shown below.

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark import Row

conf = SparkConf().setAppName("myFirstApp").setMaster("local")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

df = [Row(Z_0=0.0, Z_1=0.0)]
df = sc.parallelize(df).toDF()
for each in range(0,400):
    df = df.withColumn("Z_"+str(each+2), df['Z_'+str(each+1)]+1)
```

It is my understanding that I am in fact building an execution plan, not necessarily the data itself.  However calling the execution of the df with `collect(), count(), show()` or conversion to rdd or even deletion of the df fails to release memory.  I have been seeing 1.2GB of memory for the above task.  It seems like garbage collection has no way of cleaning up the previous intermediate `df` objects, or perhaps that these objects are never de-referenced.

is there a better method of building out this type of iterative calculation, or is there any way to cleanup these intermediate df's?  Note the simple `+1` occurring here is just a minimum example mock of much more complex calculations.

Comment: You should definitely try out a `pandas_udf` once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that you can call `take()` in order to remove the execution plan, leaving simply values.  See the last line for the relevant call.

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark import Row

conf = SparkConf().setAppName("myFirstApp").setMaster("local")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

df = [Row(Z_0=0.0, Z_1=0.0)]
df = sc.parallelize(df).toDF()
for each in range(0,1400):
    df = df.withColumn("Z_"+str(each+2), df['Z_'+str(each+1)]+1)
    df = sc.parallelize(df.take(df.count())).toDF()
```

My statement in the question about garbage collection being the issue is not quite correct. There is a difference between the `heap size` and the `used heap`.  In investigation with visualVM, it was easy to see that the garbage collection is occurring, which reduces the `used heap`.
[image]
We see that problem that the jvm has in processing the code posted in the question.  Towards the end, we have no space to move.  Our `heap size` is maxed, and the `used heap` is too big at this point, with nothing to GC. This expansion was not due to the data, but instead the data lineage information being retained.  What I needed to do was get rid of all of that lineage, which to be honest isn't all that useful in this problems context, and retain just the data.

The following is the profile of the answer code snippet above.  Even with 1400 columns, we have little problem holding the data.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have been dealing with the same thing and havent come up with a good solution.

As a **Temporary Solution :
Split The application to many .py files and execute them one by one** ,
which will cause garbage collection to free all unnecessary cache.

Comment: You can always interrupt the execution plan by calling `df.checkpoint()`

Comment: using checkpoints() also doesnt free up the cache, I have tried it.

Comment: Of course not, there are other functions like [clearCache](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.SQLContext.clearCache) which are supposed to do this.